# Loading SpriteFont through a different class than Game.cs

Tags: xna, c#, loading, xna-content-pipeline

I am trying to load up a single SpriteFont to print some debug information.
In our current game, we load up both Textures and Music through a ResourceManager. They are both loaded with a filestream, and thus do not require Content.Load

```
SoundEffect soundEffect = SoundEffect.FromStream( fs );
```

Since this ResourceManager does not inherit from Game or is like Game.cs, I cannot use the usual method:

```
SpriteFont spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(resource.Key.Item2);
```

Anyone have any idea how I can either:
-Load the SpriteFont a different way
-Create my own Contentmanager

Comment: Just send Content as parameter to the other class? This is generally how it's made. If you have a scene class(for example, not necessarily) you usually pass content (or entire game) as parameter to the class creator. So you can create your resources in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what Gustavo - Gtoknu said and pass the content manager variable into your ResourceManager class OR you could create a new content manager. You'd have to have a reference to your main `game` class, but this is the idea:

```
ContentManager content = new ContentManager(myGameRef.Services, "Content");
```

Where `"Content"` is the root directory to load content from.

Keep in mind that when the `content` variable is disposed, so are all the resources associated with it (ie. anything you loaded), so you want to keep it in scope until you're done with the resources it loaded.